# Sort by calculated element

Tags: ruby, sorting, collections

I have a collection:

```
programmers = [
  {:name => "Martin", :speed => 2.0, :daily_wage => 2000},
  {:name => "Jarda", :speed => 1.0, :daily_wage => 1300},
  {:name => "Lukas", :speed => 0.5, :daily_wage => 900},
  {:name => "Pepa", :speed => 1.7, :daily_wage => 2200},
  {:name => "Kamil", :speed => 0.4, :daily_wage => 1800},
  {:name => "Honza", :speed => 1.2, :daily_wage => 1500},
  {:name => "Filip", :speed => 1.1, :daily_wage => 1000}
]
```

I want to count their quality

```
quality = (pro[:daily_wage] / pro[:speed])
sorted << [pro[:name], pro[:speed], pro[:daily_wage], quality]
```

and sort it by quality

```
sorted.sort_by { |a| a[3] }
```

and my technique isn't working, so can you give me tips to remap this collection for further iterations over `sorted`?

Comment: What is `pro`? What is `sorted`?

Comment: Don't imitate Prince, playing with words. You are decades late. And most of all, you are rude.

Comment: Why is speed in the denominator? Speed is a vice?

Comment: In real-life, if `:speed` were determined objectively, you should check for non-positive values before doing your calculations.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I originally suggested creating a new key/value pair and sorting at the same time:

```
programmers.sort_by { |h| h[:quality] = (h[:daily_wage]/h[:speed]).round(0) }
```

When I did so I had not considered that this would require the expression in the block be calculated for both elements of each pairwise comparison done by `sort_by`.  My thanks to @Mark for pointing that out.  (See comments to his answer.)  Accordingly, I've come around to it being better to just do the replacement and sort sequentially, in the straightforward way:

```
arr = programmers.each {|h| h[:quality] = (h[:daily_wage]/h[:speed]).round(0)}
arr.sort_by {|h| h[:quality]}
  #=> [{:name=>"Filip",  :speed=>1.1, :daily_wage=>1000, :quality=> 909},
  #    {:name=>"Martin", :speed=>2.0, :daily_wage=>2000, :quality=>1000},
  #    {:name=>"Honza",  :speed=>1.2, :daily_wage=>1500, :quality=>1250},
  #    {:name=>"Pepa",   :speed=>1.7, :daily_wage=>2200, :quality=>1294},
  #    {:name=>"Jarda",  :speed=>1.0, :daily_wage=>1300, :quality=>1300},
  #    {:name=>"Lukas",  :speed=>0.5, :daily_wage=> 900, :quality=>1800},
  #    {:name=>"Kamil",  :speed=>0.4, :daily_wage=>1800, :quality=>4500}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the way I'd do it. First, put your calculation in a lambda:

```
quality = ->(pro) {pro[:daily_wage] / pro[:speed]}
```

Then you can sort the collection concisely:

```
programmers.sort_by &quality
```

This way you don't need to create an intermediate data structure just for sorting.

However, if you *do* want to permanently retain the quality measure, you can invoke the lambda for each element, adding a new key/value pair, then sort on that:

```
programmers.each{|p| p[:quality] = quality[p]}.sort_by{|p| p[:quality]}
```

Note the call of a lambda using square brackets, this is simply shorthand for `quality.call(p)`

Comment: Mark, I can see how having a lambda would be useful if you had use of it later, but if you are just going to add a key/value pair to each hash and then sort on that value, use of the lambda results in the wage/speed ratios be calculated twice (and also exposes the variable that holds the lambda).  Isn't that a disadvantage?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't combine the two approaches I outlined for the reason you mention. Also, performance could be improved by adding memoization. Expressions in `sort_by` are called more than once. (This applies to your answer too). My primary reason to use a lambda is for documentation purposes: I like to give names to the calculations so it reads like English (also, it looked like the OP was trying to implement something along those lines).

Comment: Good points, especially your observation about the expression in the block being called multiple times when sorting.  I hadn't thought of that, and will modify my answer as a result.  Thanks.

Comment: I made it clear that in the second case, you sort by the newly added  key rather than calling the lambda again (no need).